# How to connect to internet over VPN raised on virtual machine?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, vpn

I have an PC running Ubuntu, that is connected to the network of my internet provider. To access the internet, one must make a connection using l2tp or ppp, which I have failed to configure on Ubuntu.

I have a VirtualBox Windows 7 guest, where I could easily make the connection to the internet. However, as things stand now, I can only access the world wide web from inside a virtual machine, which is very unconvenient.

Is there a way to connect my host machine to the internet using connection my guest machine has established?

P.S. I have tried setting up connection using NetworkManager package, but all I have got was missing options that were needed by provider and failure to present the reasons for failure of attempted connection.

Comment: Do you have any network hardware (e.g. router) between your physical computer and the Internet jack?

Comment: No.
In fact, when i did have router, i could just set up all settings there and connect to it without a worry

Comment: Is your VM set up with a NAT address under your Windows host? Or is it bridged to your physical adapter (unlikely, as you'll need 2 ISP-provided IP addresses)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep yet to comment, so I post this as an answer.  If your internet service provider allows PPPoE connections, you can find a guide on how to do a routerless configuration for Ubuntu here:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE

I used it in the past to have 2 separate ADSL accounts in South Africa, where all ISP's use the same VPI/VCI values, meaning your router can only link to one ISP at a time.  But routers allow PPPoE pass-through, meaning the router is connected to one ISP and a server (setup as an internet proxy) can connect through the router interface to another ISP.

I used Ubuntu for that, and it work very well.  Note, after you followed that guide, your GUI tool to configure network settings in Ubuntu stops working, so be prepared to become a command-line man.